# PhoneGap "Hello World" launches in android emulator but no default PhoneGap "Device is ready" Screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova

So I have created the basic "Hello World" project using the command line against the bin folder in the android directory as instructed on the Cordova "Getting started guides". I am using PhoneGap 2.8 and I am running the latest android SDK tools V 22. I have also installed the android 4.2.2 SDK platform.

My emulator launches and the console reports the following that the project.apk has successfully been installed. There are no apparent errors.

I am able to see the "Hello World" text in the title bar at the top of the emulator but there is no default PhoneGap "Device is ready" screen that is normally called. The screen is black.

Any ideas on where I am going wrong? I am using Windows 7 environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a couple of weeks scratching my head around this I finally figured out what the problem was. I was using the PhoneGap CLI to build an android project against the bin directory. For some reason, when I opened Eclipse and started a new project with existing code (according to the PhoneGap documentation) somehow it produced an incomlplete java file. I discovered this by comparing a working application's java file with my one and realized the code was different.

So, instead of using the CLI, I simply opened Eclipse, and started a new project from the "example" folder in the PhoneGap android directory and ran the project - it worked!